react native canvas scratch game not working nor showing
i am trying to create a small scratchable game in react native. but i dont know why it is not showing up and when i add canvasRef.current in the useeffect i get this error ReferenceError: Property 'regeneratorRuntime' doesn't exist. can someone help out. i dont know where i should change. i've been doing the same way with normal react apps for web developments and till now not faced any problem. but when i wanted to start doing it on react native for mobile devices purposes it showed me this error.
i have attached the code in the snippet below.


import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Canvas from 'react-native-canvas';

const ScratchCard = () => {
const [isScratched, setIsScratched] = useState(false);
const canvasRef = useRef(null);

const handleCanvas = (canvas) => {
if (canvas) {
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// Set the size of the canvas
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 200;

// Draw the scratchable area
ctx.fillStyle = 'gray';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Draw the text beneath the scratchable area
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.font = '20px Arial';
ctx.fillText('Scratch to reveal!', 50, canvas.height / 2);
}
};

useEffect(() => {
handleCanvas(canvasRef.current);
}, []);

const handleTouchMove = (event) => {
if (isScratched) return; // If already scratched, no need to continue

const canvas = canvasRef.current;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
const touchX = event.nativeEvent.locationX - rect.left;
const touchY = event.nativeEvent.locationY - rect.top;

// Scratch off the area
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.arc(touchX, touchY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
};

const handleTouchEnd = () => {
setIsScratched(true);
};

return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<Canvas
ref={canvasRef}
style={styles.canvas}
onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}
onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd}
/>
{isScratched && <Text style={styles.message}>You've revealed the content!</Text>}
</View>
);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
},
canvas: {
width: 300,
height: 200,
},
message: {
marginTop: 20,
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: 'bold',
},
});

export default ScratchCard;




do you have regenerator-runtime installed as suggested in this answer?

Yess. I cant find why its not working. Infact only when i add the context.current in the useeffect. Is there a way to create a canva scratch animation in react native ?
